# How could I implement a generic 'not set' sentinel value for a column in a PostgreSQL table?

Tags: database, postgresql, sentinel

I'm using PostgreSQL 14 to maintain a table which acts as an append-only ledger of changes done to a `students` table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE students (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  city TEXT NOT NULL,
  mentor_of INTEGER REFERENCES students(id)
);

CREATE TABLE edits (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  student_id INTEGER REFERENCES students(id) NOT NULL,
  name TEXT,
  city TEXT,
  mentor_of INTEGER REFERENCES students(id)
);
```

Each row in the `edits` table references some student, the columns `name`, `city` and `mentor_of` give the new value to be applied to the respective column in the `student` table. A `NULL` value indicates that the field was not touched.

This works beautifully, but I lack a way to express that a column should be set to NULL. I.e. there is no way to have an `edit` row which indicates that the `duplicate_of` column of some student is to be set to `NULL`.

I considered adjusting the `edits` table such that each column is actually an *array* of one element. Thus, `NULL` indicates that e.g. the name was not touched, `{NULL}` indicates that the name was set to `NULL` and `{Jill}` indicates that the name was set to `Jill`. Unfortunately, arrays don't support foreign key constraints (yet?), so using this for the `mentor_of` column means weakening referential integrity.

I also looked into defining a [composite type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/rowtypes.html) (like `maybe_student_id` which features one boolean field to indicate set/unset and the other field gives the new value to use). Alas, composite types don't seem to support foreign keys either.

Is there a way to have a (preferably generic, i.e. not type-specific) way to get an additional sentinel value on top of `NULL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add flags (as boolean columns) to indicate the changes. This way nulls will be applied as necessary. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE edits (
  id int not null PRIMARY KEY generated by default as identity,
  student_id INTEGER not null REFERENCES students(id),
  name varchar(100),
  city varchar(50),
  mentor_of INTEGER REFERENCES students(id),
  name_modified boolean, -- added
  city_modified boolean, -- added
  mentor_of_modified boolean -- added
);
```

Of course that pollutes the design. Other option is to consolitate all flags into a boolean array, as in:

```
CREATE TABLE edits (
  id int not null PRIMARY KEY generated by default as identity,
  student_id INTEGER not null REFERENCES students(id),
  name varchar(100),
  city varchar(50),
  mentor_of INTEGER REFERENCES students(id),
  modified boolean[] -- position 0 is for name, 1 for city, etc.
);
```

Another option is to consolidate everything into a single JSON column that indicates the changes. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE edits (
  id int not null PRIMARY KEY generated by default as identity,
  student_id INTEGER not null REFERENCES students(id),
  changes json
);
```

In this case if `changes` has the value `{"name":"abc","city":null}` that means that `name` and `city` are to be modified while `mentor_of` (not mentioned) should not be touched.

Comment: Thanks for the food of thought! Do you know if it's possible to have a JSON document using foreign keys, i.e. express a constraint which dictates that in a document like `{"mentor_id": 13}` there must be a row on the `students` table with the ID 13?

Comment: @FrerichRaabe No, foreign keys can only apply to plain columns. If you want to enforce them, then the JSON option won't be useful.